# Faster method for pulling and updating items in large dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an out-of-date dictionary of thousands of items, and an updated list of thousands of items, stored as dictionaries containing the features to be updated in out-of-date dictionary, though the update list is typically smaller (but not always).

Currently, I am using two for loops to iterate though the old dictionary, and the updated list, to match up the items in the old dictionary with the correctly member of the updated list, and then overwrite the appropriate sections of the old dictionary member that have been updated (not all k,value pairs are updated and all of the pairs are never listed in the updated member).

Here is my code (**Edited**):

```
 import copy

json_lyr = {"features": [{"geometry": {"y": 92093.79407307506, "x": 1042519.5130774938},
                          "attributes": {"WildlifeSi": " ", "EditDate": 1462554757161, "Inlet_Elevation": None,
                                         "COVER_DEPT": 0, "Comments": " ", "UpBankfu_4": 0, "SteepRiffl": " ",
                                         "HeadwallMa": " ", "UpBankfu_3": 0, "UpBankfu_2": 0, "CulvertDro": 0,
                                         "OUTFLOW_BO": " ", "RoadkillWi": " ", "DnLtDomina": " ", "CrossingTy": " ",
                                         "UpBankfull": 0, "UPDATE_COM": " ", "LOCAL_REVI": " ", "RefBankf_4": 0,
                                         "RefBankf_2": 0, "RefBankf_3": 0, "RefBankf_1": 0, "CrossingCo": " ",
                                         "Flow_Condi": " ", "ID": 2209, "DnDepositT": " ", "WildlifeIn": " ",
                                         "Crossing_slope": 0, "DnDimensioB": 0, "PIPE_SPALL": " ", "RoadType": " ",
                                         "Wall_Rise": None, "DnBedrockP": " ", "UpBankArmo": " ", "DnDeposits": " ",
                                         "USER_ID": "JUNK", "Tp_Pipe_Out": None, "Wingwall_Angle": None,
                                         "AvulsionDi": 0, "Editor": "cdowd_NHSADES", "CrossDepth": " ", "UpBankfu_1": 0,
                                         "Geomorph_1": " ", "PoolDepthM": 0, "DnRtDomina": " ", "DnDimensioD": 0,
                                         "DnDimensioC": 0, "INSTALLATI": None, "DnDimensioA": 0, "UpUndermin": " ",
                                         "UpDeposits": " ", "STEEPER_WI": " ", "OUTFALL_TR": " ", "PoolDepthS": 0,
                                         "StructureM": " ", "StructureL": 0, "SED_BUILDU": " ", "OUTLET_H_1": " ",
                                         "JOINT_SEPE": " ", "DnUndermin": " ", "RAILROAD_C": " ", "UpDepositT": " ",
                                         "UpDimensio": 0, "StructureU": " ", "StructureS": " ", "UpEviEroAg": " ",
                                         "Town": " ", "CulvertWat": 0, "FloodPlain": " ", "ASSE_DATE": 1433289600000,
                                         "DnBedMater": " ", "ApproachAn": " ", "PIPE_DEFOR": " ", "Tp_pipe_Inlet": None,
                                         "DnEvidEroA": " ", "UpLtVegeta": " ", "HydCntrlTy": " ", "STORM_DRAI": " ",
                                         "Dn_Side_Ele": None, "UpBeaverDa": " ", "T2_REVIEW": " ", "PoolDepth4": " ",
                                         "DnBeaver_1": 0, "InSubstrat": " ", "SCREENING_": " ", "ChannelAvu": " ",
                                         "DRIVEWAY_C": " ", "INLET_HEAD": " ", "UpRtVegeta": " ", "MARKER_POS": " ",
                                         "HighDownst": " ", "DnBankEros": " ", "AOPCompat": " ", "DistToHydC": 0,
                                         "CulvertSlo": " ", "DnBankArmo": " ", "Observers": " ", "Dn_Hydr_Elev": None,
                                         "POINT_X": 1042519.51307749, "POINT_Y": 92093.7940730751, "Up_Side_Ele": None,
                                         "Road_Elevation": None, "DES_REVIEW": " ", "OUTLET_HEI": " ",
                                         "InDepositT": " ", "OBJECTID": 1, "UpBedMater": " ", "OUTLET_HEA": " ",
                                         "InBedMat_1": " ", "PIPE_CORRO": " ", "UpRtDomina": " ", "SCOUR_OUTL": " ",
                                         "InDeposits": " ", "NoShoulder": 0, "CULVERT_OU": " ",
                                         "Creator": "cdowd_NHSADES", "RefBankful": 0, "SteppedFoo": " ",
                                         "Pool_Btm_Elev": None, "PAINTED_MA": " ", "DnBankFull": 0, "UpBedrockP": " ",
                                         "StreamName": " ", "DnRtVegeta": " ", "Hyd_Cont_Elev": None,
                                         "GlobalID_2": "8bb7eb9e-45b2-4e16-b563-f2a44787342b", "UpBeaver_1": 0,
                                         "Outlet_Elevation": None, "Dn_to_Hydr_Cont": 0, "WildlifeUp": " ",
                                         "ROAD_NAME": " ", "StructureCount": 0, "UpLtDomina": " ", "Downstream": " ",
                                         "CulvertOverflow": " ", "Inlet_Type": None, "INFLOW_BOD": " ", "TIDAL": " ",
                                         "DnBeaverDa": " ", "CrossVelMa": " ", "UpBankEros": " ", "DnLtVegeta": " ",
                                         "UPDATE_OBS": " ", "DnBankFu_4": 0, "InBedMater": " ", "DnBankFu_1": 0,
                                         "DnBankFu_2": 0, "DnBankFu_3": 0, "RECENT_RAI": " ",
                                         "CreationDate": 1462554757161,
                                         "GlobalID": "{e5f9d928-c9c2-4c43-b7de-eeefa7820955}", "NoTravelLa": 0,
                                         "UpDimens_2": 0, "UpDimens_3": 0, "REVIEW_LEV": "Incomplete", "UpDimens_1": 0,
                                         "Jurisdicti": " ", "UPDATE_DAT": None, "EMBEDDED_D": 0, "CULVERT_IN": " ",
                                         "GeomorphCo": " "}},
                         {"geometry": {"y": 157642.015010491, "x": 1164940.328930911},
                          "attributes": {"WildlifeSi": " ", "EditDate": 1462554757161, "Inlet_Elevation": None,
                                         "COVER_DEPT": 0.25, "Comments": " ", "UpBankfu_4": 9, "SteepRiffl": "No",
                                         "HeadwallMa": "Concrete", "UpBankfu_3": 6, "UpBankfu_2": 6.5, "CulvertDro": 0,
                                         "OUTFLOW_BO": "Wetland", "RoadkillWi": "Goupher",
                                         "DnLtDomina": "Herbaceous/grass", "CrossingTy": "Box Culvert",
                                         "UpBankfull": 9.5,
                                         "UPDATE_COM": "1) Wetland present. Would argue that geomorphic compatibility determination is inappropriate in this instance. 2) What is the substrate type of material (if exists) in the structure? ",
                                         "LOCAL_REVI": " ", "RefBankf_4": 3, "RefBankf_2": 5, "RefBankf_3": 3.25,
                                         "RefBankf_1": 8, "CrossingCo": "Old", "Flow_Condi": "Typically Low",
                                         "ID": 2210, "DnDepositT": "None", "WildlifeIn": " ", "Crossing_slope": 0,
                                         "DnDimensioB": 4.1, "PIPE_SPALL": "Low", "RoadType": "Paved",
                                         "Wall_Rise": None, "DnBedrockP": "No", "UpBankArmo": "None", "DnDeposits": " ",
                                         "USER_ID": "EKINNorthRd01", "Tp_Pipe_Out": None, "Wingwall_Angle": None,
                                         "AvulsionDi": 40, "Editor": "cdowd_NHSADES", "CrossDepth": "Yes",
                                         "UpBankfu_1": 5.5, "Geomorph_1": " ", "PoolDepthM": 0,
                                         "DnRtDomina": "Shrub/sapling", "DnDimensioD": 0, "DnDimensioC": 0,
                                         "INSTALLATI": 1433808000000, "DnDimensioA": 6, "UpUndermin": "None",
                                         "UpDeposits": " ", "STEEPER_WI": "No", "OUTFALL_TR": "None", "PoolDepthS": 0,
                                         "StructureM": "Concrete", "StructureL": 35, "SED_BUILDU": "Open",
                                         "OUTLET_H_1": "Good", "JOINT_SEPE": "None", "DnUndermin": "None",
                                         "RAILROAD_C": "No", "UpDepositT": "None", "UpDimensio": 6,
                                         "StructureU": "None", "StructureS": "No", "UpEviEroAg": "None",
                                         "Town": "East Kingston", "CulvertWat": 4.5, "FloodPlain": "Not Significant",
                                         "ASSE_DATE": 1433808000000, "DnBedMater": "Cobble",
                                         "ApproachAn": "Naturally Straight", "PIPE_DEFOR": " ", "Tp_pipe_Inlet": None,
                                         "DnEvidEroA": "None", "UpLtVegeta": "Yes", "HydCntrlTy": " ",
                                         "STORM_DRAI": "No", "Dn_Side_Ele": None, "UpBeaverDa": "No", "T2_REVIEW": " ",
                                         "PoolDepth4": " ", "DnBeaver_1": 0, "InSubstrat": "NA", "SCREENING_": "No",
                                         "ChannelAvu": "Cross & Follow Road", "DRIVEWAY_C": "No", "INLET_HEAD": "Good",
                                         "UpRtVegeta": "Yes", "MARKER_POS": "NA", "HighDownst": "No",
                                         "DnBankEros": "None", "AOPCompat": " ", "DistToHydC": 0,
                                         "CulvertSlo": "About the Same", "DnBankArmo": "None", "Observers": "RPC_NLCW",
                                         "Dn_Hydr_Elev": None, "POINT_X": 1164965.05788408, "POINT_Y": 157629.355258904,
                                         "Up_Side_Ele": None, "Road_Elevation": None, "DES_REVIEW": " ",
                                         "OUTLET_HEI": "< 1 ft above Channel", "InDepositT": "None", "OBJECTID": 2,
                                         "UpBedMater": "Cobble", "OUTLET_HEA": "Concrete", "InBedMat_1": " ",
                                         "PIPE_CORRO": " ", "UpRtDomina": "Shrub/sapling", "SCOUR_OUTL": "None",
                                         "InDeposits": " ", "NoShoulder": 0, "CULVERT_OU": "At Grade",
                                         "Creator": "cdowd_NHSADES", "RefBankful": 7, "SteppedFoo": "No",
                                         "Pool_Btm_Elev": None, "PAINTED_MA": "NA", "DnBankFull": 7.33,
                                         "UpBedrockP": "No",
                                         "StreamName": "NHRIV600030805-04 GREAT BROOK - BRICKYARD BROOK",
                                         "DnRtVegeta": "Yes", "Hyd_Cont_Elev": None,
                                         "GlobalID_2": "ce43e49c-5386-4127-8db9-793228b03c13", "UpBeaver_1": 0,
                                         "Outlet_Elevation": None, "Dn_to_Hydr_Cont": 0, "WildlifeUp": "Bugs, birds",
                                         "ROAD_NAME": "Rt 108 north rd", "StructureCount": 1,
                                         "UpLtDomina": "Herbaceous/grass", "Downstream": "No", "CulvertOverflow": "No",
                                         "Inlet_Type": None, "INFLOW_BOD": "Wetland", "TIDAL": "No", "DnBeaverDa": "No",
                                         "CrossVelMa": "Yes", "UpBankEros": "None", "DnLtVegeta": "Yes",
                                         "UPDATE_OBS": " ", "DnBankFu_4": 3.5, "InBedMater": "No", "DnBankFu_1": 5.9,
                                         "DnBankFu_2": 7.75, "DnBankFu_3": 5, "RECENT_RAI": "Within 1 week",
                                         "CreationDate": 1462554757161,
                                         "GlobalID": "{89bc7cfd-b115-42ca-aa07-16ce42539c4d}", "NoTravelLa": 2,
                                         "UpDimens_2": 0, "UpDimens_3": 0, "REVIEW_LEV": "Incomplete",
                                         "UpDimens_1": 4.1, "Jurisdicti": "NH DOT", "UPDATE_DAT": None, "EMBEDDED_D": 0,
                                         "CULVERT_IN": "At Grade", "GeomorphCo": " "}}]}

update_list = [{'ID': 2209, 'GeomorphCo': 'Fail'},
               {'ID': 2210, 'GlobalID': '{e5f9d928-c9c2-4c43-b7de-eeefa7820955}'}]

updated_features_superlist = []

for feature in json_lyr['features']:
    for update_feature in update_list:
        # if the IDs match
        if feature['attributes']['ID'] == update_feature['ID']:
            updated_feature = copy.deepcopy(feature)
            for key, value in update_feature.items():
                if key == 'ID':
                    continue  # don't need to update this
                else:
                    updated_feature['attributes'][key] = update_feature[key]
            # adding to the list of features that are updated
            updated_features_superlist.append(updated_feature)
```

Where json_lyr is my out of date dictionary and update_list is my updated list of features.

With thousands of points in both the out of date dictionary and the list of dictionary updates, it takes several minutes to get through the 2 for loops.  Is there a fast method to build a list of updated features?

Also, the attributes (key,value pairs) that need to be updated vary considerably every time I run the script, from 1 attribute to dozens - thus the iteration through key,value pairs in the dictionaries stored in the update_list.

**Edit:**

Example of out-of-date feature:

```
{
    'geometry': {
        'y': 104288.95701865852,
        'x': 854862.8250714131
    },
    'attributes': {
        'WildlifeSi': None,
        'EditDate': None,
        'Inlet_Elevation': 0,
        'COVER_DEPT': 1.89999997615814,
        'Comments': None,
        'UpBankfu_4': None,
        'SteepRiffl': None,
        'HeadwallMa': 'DryFitStone',
        'UpBankfu_3': None,
        'UpBankfu_2': None,
        'CulvertDro': None,
        'OUTFLOW_BO': 'Ditch',
        'RoadkillWi': 'None',
        'DnLtDomina': None,
        'CrossingTy': 'RoundCulvert',
        'UpBankfull': None,
        'UPDATE_COM': None,
        'LOCAL_REVI': None,
        'RefBankf_4': None,
        'RefBankf_2': None,
        'RefBankf_3': None,
        'RefBankf_1': None,
        'CrossingCo': 'Old',
        'Flow_Condi': None,
        'SADES_ID': 6574,
        'DnDepositT': None,
        'WildlifeIn': None,
        'Crossing_slope': 1,
        'DnDimensioB': 0,
        'PIPE_SPALL': 'NotRated',
        'RoadType': 'Paved',
        'Wall_Rise': 0,
        'DnBedrockP': None,
        'UpBankArmo': None,
        'DnDeposits': None,
        'USER_ID': None,
        'Tp_Pipe_Out': 0,
        'Wingwall_Angle': 'NoneofThese',
        'AvulsionDi': None,
        'Editor': None,
        'CrossDepth': None,
        'UpBankfu_1': None,
        'Geomorph_1': None,
        'PoolDepthM': None,
        'DnRtDomina': None,
        'DnDimensioD': 0,
        'DnDimensioC': 0,
        'INSTALLATI': None,
        'DnDimensioA': 0.930000007152557,
        'UpUndermin': 'None',
        'UpDeposits': None,
        'STEEPER_WI': None,
        'OUTFALL_TR': 'None',
        'PoolDepthS': None,
        'StructureM': 'Plastic-Smooth',
        'StructureL': 29.8299999237061,
        'SED_BUILD': '1/4Plugged',
        'OUTLET_H_1': 'Fair',
        'JOINT_SEPE': 'None',
        'DnUndermin': 'None',
        'RAILROAD_C': 'No',
        'UpDepositT': None,
        'UpDimensio': 0.980000019073486,
        'Structure': 'None',
        'StructureS': 'No',
        'UpEviEroAg': None,
        'Town': 'Fitzwilliam',
        'CulvertWat': None,
        'FloodPlain': None,
        'ASSE_DATE': 1469033829000L,
        'DnBedMater': None,
        'ApproachAn': None,
        'PIPE_DEFOR': 'None',
        'Tp_pipe_Inlet': 0,
        'DnEvidEroA': None,
        'UpLtVegeta': None,
        'HydCntrlTy': None,
        'STORM_DRAI': 'Yes',
        'Dn_Side_Ele': 0,
        'UpBeaverDa': 'No',
        'T2_REVIEW': None,
        'PoolDepth4': None,
        'DnBeaver_1': None,
        'InSubstrat': None,
        'SCREENING_': 'No',
        'ChannelAv': None,
        'DRIVEWAY_C': 'No',
        'INLET_HEAD': 'Fair',
        'UpRtVegeta': None,
        'MARKER_POS': 'NA',
        'HighDownst': None,
        'DnBankEros': None,
        'AOPCompat': '',
        'DistToHydC': None,
        'CulvertSlo': None,
        'DnBankArmo': None,
        'Observers': 'SWRPCMCHG',
        'Dn_Hydr_Elev': None,
        'POINT_X': None,
        'POINT_Y': None,
        'Up_Side_Ele': 0,
        'Road_Elevation': 0,
        'DES_REVIEW': None,
        'OUTLET_HEI': 'AtGrade',
        'InDepositT': None,
        'OBJECTID': 6994,
        'UpBedMater': None,
        'OUTLET_HEA': 'DryFitStone',
        'InBedMat_1': None,
        'PIPE_CORRO': 'NotRated',
        'UpRtDomina': None,
        'SCOUR_OUTL': 'None',
        'InDeposits': None,
        'NoShoulder': 0,
        'CULVERT_O': None,
        'Creator': None,
        'RefBankful': None,
        'SteppedFoo': None,
        'Pool_Btm_Elev': None,
        'PAINTED_MA': 'NA',
        'DnBankFull': None,
        'UpBedrockP': None,
        'StreamName': 'NA',
        'DnRtVegeta': None,
        'Hyd_Cont_Elev': None,
        'GlobalID_2': '0544fd95-aee7-4874-9e03-fb8800b51da4',
        'UpBeaver_1': None,
        'Outlet_Elevation': None,
        'Dn_to_Hydr_Cont': None,
        'WildlifeUp': None,
        'ROAD_NAME': 'RobbinsRoad',
        'StructureCount': 1,
        'UpLtDomina': None,
        'Downstream': None,
        'CulvertOverflow': 'No',
        'Inlet_Type': 'NoneofThese',
        'INFLOW_BOD': 'Ditch',
        'TIDAL': 'No',
        'DnBeaverDa': None,
        'CrossVelMa': None,
        'UpBankEros': None,
        'DnLtVegeta': None,
        'UPDATE_OBS': None,
        'DnBankFu_4': None,
        'InBedMater': None,
        'DnBankFu_1': None,
        'DnBankFu_2': None,
        'DnBankFu_3': None,
        'RECENT_RAI': 'Within1week',
        'CreationDate': None,
        'GlobalID': None,
        'NoTravelLa': 2,
        'UpDimens_2': 0,
        'UpDimens_3': 0,
        'REVIEW_LEV': 'QAisN/A',
        'UpDimens_1': 0,
        'Jurisdicti': 'Municipal',
        'UPDATE_DAT': None,
        'EMBEDDED_D': 0,
        'CULVERT_IN': None,
        'GeomorphCo': ''
    }
}
```

Example of update list for a feature - in this case only one attribute needs to be updated:

```
{'SADES_ID': 6574, 'GeomorphCo': 'Fail'}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data format?

Comment: Why can't you just loop through the updated list and update the dictionary accordingly? I don't understand why you need to loop through the dictionary.

Comment: are you aware of the `dict.update` method? it might simplify the body of your loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not sure what you mean....

Comment: Why do you need to iterate through the `key, value` pairs? That defeats the purpose of having a dictionary.  It's hard to tell because you've given us a snippet of code completely out of context. You should give a minimum, reproducible example *that people can run*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have now added reproducible code for you to test out and show me what you mean.  It is not a true example though, because in most cases the out-of-date dictionary has thousands of entries and the update list has dozens to hundreds of entries, and they are not in any known order and certainly not a 1-to-1 match, as in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd create a dictionary mapping ID to items in `update_list`:

```
update_mapping = dict((update_feature['ID'], update_feature)
                      for update_feature in update_list)
```

And then run your loop, but use dictionary lookups instead of a `for` loop to get the `update_feature`:

```
for feature in json_lyr['layers'][0]['features']:
    if feature['attributes']['ID'] in update_mapping:
        update_feature = update_mapping[feature['attributes']['ID']]
        updated_feature = copy.deepcopy(feature)
        for key, value in update_feature.items():
            if key == 'ID': continue        # don't need to update this
            else:
                updated_feature['attributes'][key] = update_feature[key]
        # adding to the list of features that are updated
        updated_features_superlist.append(updated_feature)
```

Comment: Would you still use the same solution after reviewing the updated code and information I have provided?

Comment: This method only took 27 seconds versus several minutes for my original method.